# I want to apply an additional texture to my cup on the faces selected in the top screenshot. But the Normal UV map currently takes up all space

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-baking, normal-map

The cup is from Blender Guru's tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIUDZZMfGNI&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&index=18

Now I want to add a new texture on the side of the cup just to see if I can, it will be a transparent logo I made in photoshop, so it's not water droplets.

I figured adding a new material slot would work to then apply a new texture - but it quickly gets lost when I try to select the face on the cup, maybe I am doing something wrong in setting up the new material, if at all that is what I need to do.

Do I add a new UV map somehow, if so how do I plug it in?

I am quite new to Blender (2.92.0)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Here's how you do it.

First add a new material: Select your object and in materials settings press the +, then press New and name your material.

[image]

Next create a new UV vertex group, and unwrap it: Switch to UV Edit mode. Select the vertices or faces you want to add your new material too. Add a new UV Map and name it, then <kbd>U</kbd> unwrap your selected vertices, make sure you have your new UV Map selected in the active UV layer in the upper right corner of the image editor window.

[image]

Assign your texture: Back to Layout mode. In Edit Mode. Keep your vertices or faces selected, make sure the new material is selected in the Materials settings window, click Assign. Then you have to add the image texture. Go to the Shader Editor. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to add nodes. Add an Image Texture node and a UVMap node, set it up like in the image below. Depending on the look you're after, you may want to adjust some settings, like Transmission and Roughness.

[image]

Yours will look better than this with some fine adjustments.

[image]

Comment: This is what I got so far following your advise and it does show up on the side of the cup woohoo! https://i.imgur.com/BJqjbIy.png

However on the front side of the cup there is a small clipping of the logo: https://i.imgur.com/lzmAiTq.png

And selecting all vertices on the cup show the overall grid is overlaying the UV mapping: https://i.imgur.com/qJqDbwG.png — it's the mesh-layout I used for the condensation as seen in my first screenshot. How do I fix this without messing up the condensation?

Comment: Alright a little progress, I didn't realise at first that the location of the unwrapped UV mesh are identical to your original unwrapped mesh once you make a new UV map. I simply moved the large mesh out of the way while I had the new UV map selected (and the original mesh is in place on the normal!). 

I have now added my transparent png and mapped it to my cup, it is now coming out TOO transparent though, you can barely make out the blue effect on the cup: https://i.imgur.com/m4qBQY6.png Any ideas?

Comment: @Svisha You've got Transmission set to 1 on the principled shader of your logo texture, if you want the logo to remain opaque this should be 0. Transmission is a shader's transparency. I added Transmission on the setup I posted above so the drops could be seen through the image. If you want condensation on the outside of the cup, over the image, that is a little more complicated, but let me know I can edit the answer. Make sure the drops or condensation are mapped to the interior faces of the glass cup and not the exterior faces where you will have placed your logo.

Comment: I ended up with this node setup and it works, indeed I also had to make sure Transmission was set to 0: https://i.imgur.com/Ja8aVzb.png

Comment: You can take the Alpha from the Image Texture node and plug it into the Alpha input at the bottom of the Principled shader, and avoid having two Principled Shaders.